# Add columns in magento table "Newsletter-subscription"

Tags: magento-1.7

I want to add multiple columns in "Newsletter Subscriber". my module name is Test_Advancenewsletter
For this I  made sql->advancenewsletter_setup->mysql4-install-0.1.0.php and write

```
    $installer = $this;
    $installer->startSetup();
    $installer->run("
    ALTER TABLE {$this->getTable('newsletter_subscriber')}
        ADD (`lastname` TEXT NULL,
              `address` TEXT NULL,
              `phoneno` INT(20) NULL);
         "); 
    $installer->endSetup();
```

in config.xml I write:-

```
 <resources>
            <advancenewsletter_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Test_Advancenewsletter</module>
                    <class>Test_Advancenewsletter_Model_Resource_Mysql4_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </advancenewsletter_setup>
      </resources>
```

But It doesn’t create column. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution Basically First I made a column name Firstname. Then I try to add multiple columns. so I forget to remove resource from core resource table. 
I means to say that when we define resource than it save resource name in core resource table. So next time it will check resource name if it exit then it doesn’t do anything. So if we want to run sql query again then we have to remove resource name.